# jQuery: on keypress in input field trigger an action

Tags: jquery

I have a small input window with id of "#property_id". I am trying to achieve running the function "mapSettleTime()" on pressing the enter key. This code below is not working. Any suggestions?

```
$('#property_id').keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13) {
    mapSettleTime();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what actually worked:

```
$(document).on('keydown','#property_id', function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13) {
    mapSettleTime();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add keyCode:

```
$('#property_id').on('keypress',function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13) {
    mapSettleTime();
  }
});
```

Comment: If I remember correctly e.which works under IE, keyCode works in every other browser, or in all browsers. So just use both of them, just in case:)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Got it working like this:

```
$('body').keypress(function (e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if ($("#YOURID").is(':focus')) {
        if(key == 13)  // the enter key code
        {
            // Do something like mapSettleTime();
        }
    }
});
```

I had to attach the listener to the body and check if my input field is focused.
Attaching the listener to the field itself didnt work. (dont know why)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#property_id').keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode==13)
  {
    mapSettleTime();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#property_id').bind('keypress',function(e) {
   if(e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13) {
      mapSettleTime();
   }
});
```